# Asp.net adding weird encoded chars to url

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, url, decode, encode

i have this link with the url `/laws/document?ref=S-AL1_2_36458`.

when clicking on it, weird characters are being added. the characters are:

`%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B`

so the url will end being:

`/laws/document?ref=S-AL1_2_36458%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B`

when encoding the original link in `js` (using `encodeURI()`) it returns the same weird link. however, when encoding just the "ref value"
which is `S-AL1_2_3645` it doesn't add weird chars

Answer (score 0):

`%E2%80%8B` is URL encoded sequence for the Unicode character [ZERO WIDTH SPACE (U+200B)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm). This appears repeated 5 times in your URL.

So it seems, that the link isn’t actually just `/laws/document?ref=S-AL1_2_36458` but it is `/laws/document?ref=S-AL1_2_36458<ZWSP><ZWSP><ZWSP><ZWSP><ZWSP>` which the browser will then encode properly in order to make the request. This behavior is expected and correct if that’s the actual URL that is being navigated to.

If this is not the URL that you want, I would suggest you to check the HTML of the link. If this is a static HTML, then check if there are any characters at the end of the URL and remove them. Since they are spaces of zero-width, they are effectively invisible but there are still there (e.g. in text editors, you will notice them when moving your cursor). If this is a generated link, check where the value comes from and try to trim any whitespace around the source.